Storing password in your Keychain failed: OS X Keychain error (OSStatus -25293)
I am using the MapTiler plugin which requires an authentication key (it is the only entry in my Authentication database in Preferences). Every time I restart QGIS I have to re-enter my password and I get the error message "Storing password in your Keychain failed: OS X Keychain error (OSStatus -25293)". Any clues as to how to resolve this?

As described here on QGIS github the trick is to go into Keychain Access, search for QGIS, open up that entry, select Access Control and change the setting to "Allow all applications to access this item". Importantly do this with QGIS closed.
